# Using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am totally new to `ReactJS` and `Material-UI` so I am getting a lot errors in the `makestyles()` can anyone help me with code?

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { alpha } from "@mui/material";

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
    title: {
      display: 'none',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        display: 'block',
      },
    },
    search: {
      position: 'relative',
      borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
      backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
      '&:hover': { backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25) },
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
      marginLeft: 0,
      width: '100%',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: { marginLeft: theme.spacing(3), width: 'auto' },
    },
    searchIcon: {
      padding: theme.spacing(0, 2), height: '100%', position: 'absolute', pointerEvents: 'none', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    inputRoot: {
      color: 'inherit',
    },
    inputInput: {
      padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0), paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`, transition: theme.transitions.create('width'), width: '100%', [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: { width: '20ch' },
    },
    toolbar: {
      display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
  }));
```

errors I am getting:

**1)** *MUI: The styles argument provided is invalid. You are providing a function without a theme in the context. One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.*

**2)** *Uncaught TypeError: theme.breakpoints is undefined*

Comment: Welcome. Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: If you are new to MUI and starting out with v5, you should not use `makeStyles`. It is the [legacy styling solution](https://mui.com/styles/basics/) from v3 and v4 and is deprecated in v5. The main replacements in v5 are [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/) and the [sx prop](https://mui.com/components/box/#the-sx-prop).